# Obtener el primer logo_path e ignorar el resto en una respuesta JSON API de TMDB

Tags: php, json, api

Tengo un problema espero me puedan ayudar.

Estoy haciendo un pequeño script que muestre entre otras cosas plataformas de Streaming de una producción usando para esto la API de Themoviedb.org.

Sin embargo hay algunas producciones que tienen más de una plataforma de streaming por ejemplo

```
/** Example response
 *     "MX": {
 *     "link": "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/1081291-faraway/watch?locale=MX",
 *     "flatrate": [
 *       {
 *         "logo_path": "/t2yyOv40HZeVlLjYsCsPHnWLk4W.jpg",
 *         "provider_id": 8,
 *         "provider_name": "Netflix",
 *         "display_priority": 0
 *       },
 *       {
 *         "logo_path": "/mShqQVDhHoK7VUbfYG3Un6xE8Mv.jpg",
 *         "provider_id": 1796,
 *         "provider_name": "Netflix basic with Ads",
 *         "display_priority": 55
 *       }
 *     ]
 *   },
 */
```

Y cuando intento que se coloque el logo en un html con:

```
   if ($streaming_logo_path != '') {
        echo '<img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' . $streaming_logo_path . '" alt="' . $streaming . '" style="width:100px; margin:10px;">';
    } else {
        echo 'No disponible';
    }
```

No me coloca una imagen valida porque combina los 2 "logo_path" que incluye la respuesta.

Como puedo tomar solo el primer logo_path e ignorar el resto?

He intentado con:

```
$streaming_logo_path = "";
if ($type == "movie") {
    $streaming_logo_path .= "Streaming: ";
    if (isset($data1['results']['MX']['flatrate'])) {
        $streaming_logo_path .= " ";
        foreach ($data1['results']['MX']['flatrate'] as $flatrate) {
            $streaming_logo_path .= $flatrate['logo_path'] . " ";
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    $streaming_logo_path .= "Streaming: ";
    if (isset($data1['results']['MX']['flatrate'])) {
        $streaming_logo_path .= " ";
        foreach ($data1['results']['MX']['flatrate'] as $flatrate) {
            $streaming_logo_path .= $flatrate['logo_path'] . " ";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo el problema persiste, o bien que se coloquen todas las imagenes, cualquiera de las 2 me funcionaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre obtener solo el primer logo con esta sencilla línea.

Espero le funcione a alguien más:

```
$streaming_logo_path = $data1['results']['MX']['flatrate'][0]['logo_path'];
```

Gracias.